# How to solve MemoryError in conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, out-of-memory, conda, pyomo

I'm trying to run a pyomo script in conda environment but, not sure why, it takes a huge amount of time and finally prints a Memory Error.
The main point is that I did the same thing on a virtual machine and it works perfectly. Any ideas?

System: ubuntu 16.04
Conda 4.7.12

this is the script that i usually run with python (python script.py)

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import sys

model = AbstractModel()
model.n = Param() 
model.T = RangeSet(1, model.n)
model.a = Param(model.T)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='N.csv', range='N', param=model.n)
data.load(filename='A.csv', range= 'A', param=model.a)

def somma(model):
    return sum(model.a[t] for t in model.T)

model.obj= Objective(rule=somma)

instance = model.create_instance(data)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(instance) 
instance.solutions.store_to(results)

stdout_backup = sys.stdout

with open('results.yml', 'a') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    results.write()

sys.stdout = stdout_backup

results.write()
```

and this is the error

```
File "/home/chiara/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/libmp/libelefun.py", line 76, in <module>
    cache_prec_steps += [min(2**k,LOG_TAYLOR_PREC)+20] * 2**(k-1)
MemoryError
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>(177): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(178): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(182): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(183): <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(185):
```

Comment: But the problem is that if I run it on vm it works, on the host it crashes. And the script is exactly the same. It's a very simple abstract model but it has a solution.

Comment: Are you running the VM on the same host?

Comment: yes I am. The only difference is that on the vm I have installed ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Check if you installed Python 32bit with Anaconda that sounds like it could be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the GMP 6.2.0 build 0 in conda-forge and was fixed in 6.2.0 build 1. Updating gmp using `conda update gmp` should fix this issue.